# Principles of Mathematical Analysis by W.Rudin: Indian edition

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation

Searching on Amazon for Rudin's book, I found two different editions with a big difference in price. The first is characterized as an Indian version (3rd edition) while the other is the standard textbook, being more expensive. Does anyone know if the the quality of the indian version is good? I assume that the language is english and the content is exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, the content is the same. I believe this edition is supposed to be sold only in India and some neighboring countries.

Comment: I would like to get some feedback from someone in the community that owns this version. The reviews from amazon are conflicting.

Comment: @AlexandrosB Yes it is nice in print and exactly same in content, I have that book.

Comment: I own all books of Rudin and some of them (including baby Rudin , RCA and FA) are Indian editions. I learnt most of my Mathematics from these books and they have the same content as International Editions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, just ordered it!

Comment: The International or Indian editions of a textbooks are usually just the same books as the USA edition, but [priced differently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_discrimination), distributed regionally and have probably different print qualities.

Comment: It seems that as of 2012, India is a member of most of the international copyright conventions, and thus can no longer publish books like this?